# JavaPN throws SSLHandshakeException java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I am developing a Push Notification service in Java for apple, and for that i have used [JavaPNS 2.2](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/). I have used tutorials available at this [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) to create my certificates in Apple and run the demo (in PHP), successfully. (I have also converted the certificates in .p12, .pem files).

However when i try to run the simple push notification in java in my test class (As specified in JavaPNS tutorial),

```
public class PushTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
         List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.alert("Hello World!", "<filename>.p12", "<password>", true, "<devicetoken>");
         System.out.println("List of Device: "+notifications);

         List<Device> inactiveDevices = Push.feedback("<filename>.p12", "<password>", true);
    } catch (CommunicationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeystoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am getting,

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:402)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:350)
    at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:320)
    at javapns.Push.sendPayload(Push.java:177)
    at javapns.Push.test(Push.java:132)
    at javapns.test.NotificationTest.pushTest(NotificationTest.java:83)
    at javapns.test.NotificationTest.main(NotificationTest.java:46)
```

After debugging the JavaPNS code in eclipse i come to know the error was due to,

```
java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

Now i am not understanding what is the problem, as my certificates (with .PEM extensions) works fine with PHP example.

If its working in PHP and not in Java i am doubtful weather its certificates' fault, and JavaPNS site also not specified weather i have to import the generated certificates through `keytool` or not.

Can anyone please help me solve my problem?
FYI: My System Configuration,
OS: Win 7
Java : jdk1.6.0_05
JavaPNS : 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found answer to my question,

Its the certificate. The thing is, there are 2 certificates with the same URL (com.xxx.xxx) and because of which the confusion occurred.

I have removed the one not used by the device and created a new .p12 from the one used in the device and Bingo, it worked.